# Rake db:migrate not working with pg Gem. How to fix error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 + pg Gem + AWS Cloud9. When trying to "rake db:setup" I'm having following error:

```
$ rake db:setup
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I was using the following tutorial: https://medium.com/@noordean/setting-up-postgresql-with-rails-application-357fe5e9c28

Here is my files:

/app/config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_HOST'] %>
development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DB'] %>
test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_TEST_DB'] %>
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DB'] %>
```

/app/.env

```
POSTGRES_USER='user'
POSTGRES_PASSWORD='user'
POSTGRES_HOST='localhost'
POSTGRES_DB='your_database_name'
POSTGRES_TEST_DB='your_database_name_test'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have postrges running on your machine, try to connect with psql on your terminal

`psql -U user -d your_database_name`

Comment: I got following error: psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: That’s the answer, you need to have Postgres installed and running on your laptop